# Service that receive updates from server then show it to user

Tags: android

I want to create an android service that do the following:

- run all the time.
- interact with more than activity.
- listen to the server.
- when receive a response from server add it to the user interface.
- user can send requests or data to server.
- i want the service to handle multiple requests simultaneously.

Can any one help me please....

Comment: I can give u service but internal implementations you need to do.

Comment: did you mean service class and aidl ?

Comment: U dont need aidl if i m not wrong looking at ur requirement

Comment: i saw this tutorial [link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/).... is it useful?

Comment: it is nice. But its using aidl. u dont need this. its too much for requirement.

Comment: i added new requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[link](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) download the sample and tryout code.